# Re-inflate different layout View in same Fragment in onResume

Tags: android

I have a `Fragment`, `MainFragment`, which can contain two, three, or four nested fragments. The specific fragments that will be shown can be changed by the user in the settings.

There is a different layout for each number of fragments. For instance, `layout_3` is used when the user chooses three nested fragments.

What I need to do is dynamically update `MainFragment`'s layout, and which fragments will be nested within that layout, in `onResume()` (*i.e.* Once the user comes back from the settings). There are about 10 fragments the user can choose from, and I need to be able to swap them in and out of `MainFragment` dynamically.

I'm having trouble doing this. The only way to update the layout/view once I return from the settings is to leave `MainFragment` and then come back (which calls `onCreateView()`).

Here is an example of what I do in `onCreateView()` to initialize the layouts (two nested fragments is the default):

```
mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, mParent, false);
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer1, fragment1).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer2, fragment2).commit();
return view;
```

Suppose the user then goes to the settings and chooses to have three nested fragments. This is what I've tried in `onResume()`, to no effect:

```
mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_3, mParent, false);
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer1, fragment1)).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer2, fragment2).commit();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer3, fragment3).commit();
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. Ideally, I would just force `MainFragment` to call `onCreateView()` again, but none of the solutions for that problem seem to work.

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

**Edit:** I believe the problem is with inflating the new `View`, rather than replacing the fragments.

For instance, suppose the default screen is `layout_4`, with four fragment containers. The user then goes to the settings un-checks all four default fragments, and chooses three new fragments. In `onResume()`, we try to inflate `layout_3`, and then add the fragments. I think `layout_3` never inflates, *but* because my fragment containers have the same style `id` across layouts (*i.e.* `fragmentContainer1` - `fragmentContainer4`), the first three fragment containers are updated. The fourth one remains as it was, since I assumed we were in `layout_3` and did not try to update it.

This behavior is confirmed and results in a crash when the user tries to *increase* the number of fragments, rather than decrease. Above, when the user switched from four fragments to three fragments, there was no crash because all three fragment containers I tried to update exist in `layout_4`. But if the user is in `layout_2` and then goes to the settings to select a third fragment, we'll try to add a fragment to `fragmentContainer3` when we resume. This results in a crash because `layout_3` fails to inflate.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c005f`

Any ideas how to fix this? The call to re-inflate `mView` in `onResume()` does not seem to have any effect.

**Edit 2:** I've tried calling `mParent.addView(mView)` after inflating, but still experience the same behavior as above, for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

When you return from the settings, `onResume()` should be called in the `MainFragment` and subsequently any nested fragments that were already loaded in the `MainFragment`. Can you not include any update logic in the nested fragments' `onResume()` instead of only in `onCreateView()`?

Otherwise you can create a different code path and put update logic there: make public methods in the classes for `fragment1`, `fragment2`, `fragment3` that include all your update logic, and call those methods from somewhere in `MainFragment`. (You could create an interface and have the nested fragment classes inherit that interface, if they are different classes and you want to have a cleaner design.)

Be careful about whether or not the nested fragments have been resumed yet—calling methods on View objects when nested fragments' `onResume()` hasn't been called yet could be problematic.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The nested fragments will actually never need to be updated themselves from `MainFragment` - they take care of that themselves. All I need to update is *which* fragments will be nested within the layout of `MainFragment`. There is a list of about 10 fragments the user can choose from, and I need to swap them in and out dynamically.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Usually simply adding to the fragment manager, like you did, should work in `onResume()`. (However, in your question you have two closing parentheses `fragment1))` - this would be a syntax error - is this in your original code?) One thing you could try is to create a Handler and call the Handler's postDelayed method, with the fragmentManager add code and a delay of 100-1000ms. If that works, it means there's a problem adding a fragment in `onResume()`. This would surprise me, but in some cases (e.g. `ListView`) I've had a similar bug happen, thought I would mention it.